# JavaScript filter data from array

Tags: javascript, filtering

I have 3 arrays: firstname, lastname, email:

```
var names = firstname.map(a => a.firstname);

    var uniqueNames = [];
    $.each(names, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
    });

    var lastnames = lastname.map(a => a.lastname);


    var uniqueLastNames = [];
    $.each(lastnames, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueLastNames) === -1) uniqueLastNames.push(el);
    });

    var emails = email.map(a => a.email);
```

and I'm trying to filter the array of emails by first names (how it will be followed by names):

```
var result = emails.filter(email => !uniqueNames.find(name => email.includes(name)));
```

it work when I use example:

```
var emails = ['sAdam1@green.com','lessio@gmail.com'];
```

email: sAdam1@green.com is deleted. Good result, but when I use:
`var emails = email.map(a => a.email);` Doesn't work

`console.log(emails);` is giving result like a array of string: ["mail@example.com","mail2@example.com",...]

Raw data:
emails: john.doe@example.com, doe@hotmail.com, j.doe@gmail.com, dennis@gmail.com, cow@boy.com
firstname: john, dennis, alice
lastname: doe

and result mail array: cow@boy.com. rest to the trash.

Looking forward to the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add the raw data and the wanted result as well.

Comment: I can't suggest an answer unless you give me the desired format & form of result.

Comment: im using Laravel Eloquent to get data from Mail Table (columns: firstname, lastname, email) in DB, and loads them into javascript like a names, lastnames, emails (they are like a objects of arrays) so I am getting value with map. In result I have 3 arrays of data like a names = ["john","dennis","nina"], the same with lastnames, and mails. How can I give you better informations?

Comment: it would be easier, if you add the real raw arrays with objects to the question. to get unique values, you could take a different approach, but until you do not add something, it is not possible to write some code for it. even my answer looks to small problem, which might not address the whole picture.

Comment: I understand, so i will add more informations because i was trying your code and other solutions but it doesnt work. Gimme a moment

Answer (score 2):

You could filter by checking with an array of the unwanted names.

```js
var emails = ['john.doe@example.com', 'doe@hotmail.com', 'j.doe@gmail.com', 'dennis@gmail.com', 'cow@boy.com'],
    firstnames = ['john', 'dennis', 'alice'],
    lastnames = ['doe'],
    names = [...firstnames, ...lastnames],
    filtered = emails.filter(e => !names.some(n => e.includes(n)));
    
console.log(filtered);
```